# Rails : Testing production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing

We're working on a Rails 3 project and testing using Capybara/RSpec. The problem is that the staging and production environment differ somewhat. Sometimes, the tests will run fine and there will be no problem on staging, but will break in production.

An example is when we added a middleware that uses Rack::File to send files. The application sent the header 'X-Sendfile' which works under Apache but Nginx expects 'X-Accel-Redirect'.

I'm looking for the best way to run a battery of tests when we push to production. Has anyone done this? Ideally the tests should not be run on the production server itself.

The tests would basically cover the core features of our product and would be different from the tests we are currently running.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Something I've learned the hard way is: code and deploy to environments which are identical to production. Can you change the Apache server for Nginx? I usually configure a VM with the exact same configuration as production (OS wise) and deploy / test / run the app there.

Comment: I agree that this would be the ideal situation, but our sysadmin just doesn't have time in the foreseeable future. Also, I'm not sure we can be exactly like production.

Comment: Can you build it? Install VMware Player or BusyBox with the same version of OS and patch level. By 'identical' I mean as similar as possible, so you can test this type of scenarios. I'm (quite) sure that if you ask your sysadmin to give you a hand, with the benefit that you won't need his time as often, he'll agree. It will give you freedom to test some 'edge' cases and it will free the sysadmin to do some real work rather than being a help desk... I'm sure you can convince him/her!!

Comment: Thanks for your input Augusto, but this is not what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I ended up doing is have another set of RSpec test in a production_test environment that has read-only access to the database. I use the capybara-webkit driver and each test starts by visiting the complete URL for that test.